# Irreducibility of Schur polynomials

Tags: schur-functions, polynomials, co.combinatorics

A natural question covering both [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98043) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98474/is-an-elementary-symmetric-polynomial-an-irreducibile-element-in-the-polynomial-r) question would be

*Let $n>2$. Describe Young diagrams $\lambda$ with at most $n$ nonempty rows (or equivalently non-increasing sequences $\lambda=(\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\ldots\ge\lambda_n\ge0$) for which the Schur polynomial $$s_\lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n):=\frac{\det(x_i^{\lambda_j+n-j})}{\det(x_i^{n-j})}$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.*

**Partial results:**

1. Of course, for $\lambda_n>0$, this polynomial is divisible by $s_{1^n}=e_n$ , and so isn't irreducible. (This is a generalisation of the fact that $e_k=s_{1^k}$ can only be irreducible for $k< n$ (which is shown to be true in an answer to one of the questions linked above).
2. For $\lambda=(m)$, we have $s_\lambda=h_m$, and so one of the questions linked above shows that $s_\lambda$ is irreducible.
3. For $\lambda=(n-1,n-2,\ldots,0)$ we have $s_\lambda=\prod_{i< j}(x_i+x_j)$ by Vandermonde, which is *very* reducible.

Of course, it is mere curiousity forcing me to ask it, but I think that this question has a potential to have a meaningful answer.

Comment: Basic observation: If $GCD(\lambda_1+n-1, \lambda_2+n-2, \dots, \lambda_{n-1}+1, \lambda_n) = g >1$, then $\prod_{i< j} (x_i^g-x_j^g)/(x_i-x_j)$ divides $s_{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $g=\gcd(\lambda_1+n-1,\lambda_2+n-2,\dots,\lambda_n)$. And let $V _g(X)=\prod _{i < j}\frac{x_i^g-x_j^g}{x_i-x_j}$. David already mentioned that $s_{\lambda}(X)$ is divisible by $V_g(X)$. This is in fact all that can happen.

**Theorem:** For every partition $\lambda$ (with $\lambda_n=0$), the polynomial $\frac{s_{\lambda}(X)}{V_g(X)}$ is either constant or irreducible.

This follows from theorem 3.1 in the paper ["Newton functions generating symmetric fields and irreducibility of Schur polynomials"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870809002059) by Dvornicich and Zannier.

A result which is somewhat more general is stated and proved in ["On the irreducibility of irreducible characters of simple Lie algebras"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5300). They extend the irreducibility above to characters of irreducible representations of simple Lie algebras divided by a Weyl denominator type factor (analog of $V_g$ above). Schur functions are a special case corresponding to $GL_n$.

Comment: Oh that's lovely. I would have never guessed to look there. Thanks a million!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: the answer to the original question is "$s_\lambda$ is irreducible if and only if $\lambda_n=0$ and $g=1$". 

Comment: I was looking at the paper by Dvornicich and Zannier as mentioned by Gjergji Zaimi above. I think you have stated the Theorem correctly, but there is one problem. If you read the proof carefully, you will find that the Theorem is proved, in one variable at a time, over other variables, using Galois theory. In simple word, irreducibility of polynomial $f$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is different from irreducibility of $f$ in $x_n$ over $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}]$.  Please check this out, and post if I am wrong. Thanks.